# How to get data from database using drop down list and display into input fields in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

When I select one of the year from drop-down list so, how to show the title that related to year into input fields of the form below.

```
$formationSQL = "SELECT title FROM formationacademique";
$result =  $connection->query($formationSQL);




 <form method="post">
     <label>Select year:</label>
                    <select>
      <?php foreach($result as $formation): ?>
                        <option id="formationID" name="formationID" value="<?= $formation['ID_Formation']; ?>"><?= $formation['year']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>

              <label>title:</label>
                    <input type="text value="">
        </form>
```

Comment: are you looking for php loading a value or javascript that changes on the page?

Comment: @RudyLister only php loading year record from mysql database into drop down list and then when I select one of the year from drop down so a title related to year must display into title input field.

Comment: @RudyLister my drop down list is working correctly just want to display title into input field related to year.

Comment: I am not sure if your data has a title value or if you are using the ID_Formation as a title.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some changes that are needed for your html formatting. Would need to know if you are wanting this change to happen with javascript or in php? If you don't know the difference, it is that php is server side that will only parse on page load and javascript can do it without a page refresh or reload.

```
$formationSQL = "SELECT title FROM formationacademique";
$result =  $connection->query($formationSQL);

<form method="post">

        <label for="formationID">Select year:</label>
        <select id="formationID" name="formationID">

          <?php foreach($result as $formation): ?>
            <option value="<?php $formation['ID_Formation']; ?>"><?= $formation['year']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

  <label for="input_title">title:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input_title" name="input_title" value="<?php $formation['ID_Formation']; ?>">
</form>
```

Add the following script contents to your js file or add the script after the form above for the javascript verse of changing the inputs value.

```
<script>
var year_select = document.getElementById( 'formationID' );
var year_title = document.getElementById( 'input_title' );
year_select.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ) {
  year_title.value = year_select.selectedIndex.value;
});
</script>
```